# Function in VBA Excel with IF

Tags: excel, vba, function

Hi stackoverflow community, I have issue with the following code, I'd like to create a Function that if "CONDITION" is true then sum the selected cells and if not subtract.

```
 Function balance(condition As Double, amount As Integer, residue As Integer)
 
     If condition = "PAGO" Or "PAGO AGENC" Then 
         balance = amount - residue
     ElseIf Tipo = "DEBITO" Then 
         balance = amount + residue
     End If

     balance = Application.Round(balance, 2) 

End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several small corrections:

```
Function balance(condition As String, amount As Integer, residue As Integer)

If condition = "PAGO" Or condition = "PAGO AGENC" Then
    balance = amount - residue
ElseIf condition = "DEBITO" Then
    balance = amount + residue
End If
balance = Application.Round(balance, 2)
End Function
```

Comment: Just one note: if both values ​​(both amount and residue) are of type Integer, then using Round is unnecessary. Since we are talking about money, most likely the type of these variables is Double

Answer (score 2):

Same as **Gary's Student**, but added a warning line in case the condition is not "PAGO", not "PAGO AGENC" or "DEBITO":

```
Function balance(condition As String, amount As Double, residue As Double) As Variant
    If condition = "PAGO" Or condition = "PAGO AGENC" Then
        balance = Application.Round(amount - residue, 2)
    ElseIf condition = "DEBITO" Then
        balance = Application.Round(amount + residue, 2)
    Else
        balance = "Wrong condition!"
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Very nice use of `Variant` *(+1)*